# Is it possible to display the source of MathJax-rendered TeX inline?

Tags: ipython, mathjax, jupyter-notebook

I am reading [this book](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-1/#classifier) where there are MathJax formulas. I am taking notes in an Ipython notebook. It is not convenient to take note from passages with Math formula. Is there an easy way to copy text with equations as a Tex command (which is render-able on Ipython)?

Comment: What do you mean by `MathJax` formula? You write Math expression in `TeX` form using `\(...\)` for inline delimiters. Once the webpage displays the Math using MathJax you can right click on the Math and the menu that appears gives you the options to copy MathML and Tex commands associated with the corresponding Math expression. You can try it using the [quadratic formula here](https://www.tuhh.de/MathJax/test/sample-tex.html). If I misunderstood you question, you can clarify a bit more.

Comment: hey @nam, I clarified the question. Please take a look. And a million thanks in advance :)

Comment: @nam's comment tells you how get individual equations. For larger segments, your best shot is to switch MathJax to its PlainSource output which will leave the TeX in the page. You'll still need to add math delimiters after copying though.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger I tried it before and it was very time consuming. I was wondering if I can enable a flag to embed the TeX commands of formulas in the context. Then I can just do a normal copy/pasting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

#### TL;DR

1. Right click on a formula > Math Settings > Math Renderer > MathML
2. Create a [bookmarklet](http://www.howtogeek.com/189358/beginner-geek-how-to-use-bookmarklets-on-any-device/) from: `javascript:(function() { var inline = document.getElementsByClassName("MathJax_MathML"); for (var i = 0; i < inline.length; i++) { var math = inline[i]; math.innerHTML = '<span>$</span>' + math.innerHTML + '<span>$</span>'; } })()`
3. Run the bookmarklet on a page by pressing it
4. Enjoy easier copy & pasting!

#### Long version

[This Github issue](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/1450#event-641946347) has a fix for the problem. It didn't work well for [this page](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-1/#classifier) so I changed it a bit as above. It is not a general solution, but you can tweak it depending on the specifics of a page. If you are more eager, you can elaborate on it and make a browser extension for everyone to appreciate it :).

### Old Answer

I tried couple of methods on [**this example**](https://www.tuhh.de/MathJax/test/sample-tex.html):

#### Method 1:

1. Change the settings to render as MathML by: Right click on the formula > Math Settings > Math Renderer > MathML
2. Open the page source e.g. `Ctrl + U` on Chrome or Right click and press 'View Source'.
3. Find the piece of text you are looking for. It should be displayed in the right format:

```
bla bla $a \ne 0$ bla bla \(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\) bla bla 
$$x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.$$
```

#### Method 2:

1. Do step 1 from previous method. The example page will be rendered with formulas but without the formula-enclosing characters.
2. Add single or double dollar signs around TeX commands to get the format as in step 3 of the previous method.

The best would be to combine the two method; i.e. getting the right format directly in the page. Let us know if you found a way to do it.

And thanks to @nam and @PeterKrautzberger for their hints :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my extension to @Thoran's answer with [bookmarklet](https://superuser.com/questions/279107/add-a-bookmarklet-in-google-chrome/1341468#1341468) that can auto change renderer to MathML and display MathJax formulas source inline:

`javascript: (function() { MathJax.Hub.setRenderer("NativeMML"); MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Rerender", MathJax.Hub]); MathJax.Hub.Queue(function () { var inline = document.getElementsByClassName("MathJax_MathML"); for (var i = 0; i < inline.length; i++) { var math = inline[i]; math.innerHTML = '$' + math.innerHTML + '$'; } }); })()`

And here is [PlainSource](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/output-processors/PlainSource.html) version:

`javascript: (function() { MathJax.Hub.setRenderer("PlainSource"); MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Rerender", MathJax.Hub]); MathJax.Hub.Queue(function () { var inline = document.getElementsByClassName("MathJax_PlainSource"); for (var i = 0; i < inline.length; i++) { var math = inline[i]; math.innerHTML = '$' + math.innerHTML + '$'; } }); })()`